# Hyper-parameters which minimize the variance of transformed multi-variate Guassian variable

Tags: optimization, hyperparameter, importance-sampling, optimal

Let $k < p$ be positive integers and $g: \mathbb R^k \rightarrow \mathbb R^p$ be a smooth Lipschitz continuous function. Let $y_1,\ldots, y_N \in \mathbb R^p$ and $a = (a_1,\ldots,a_N) \in \mathbb R^N$ be fixed. For each $i=1,\ldots,N$, define $e_i(y, a) := \|y-y_i\|^2_2 - a_i$, for $y \in \mathbb R^p$. Now, for positive real numbers $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_N$ and for a standard $k$-dimensional Gaussian random variable $Z$, and for each $i=1,\ldots,N$, consider the transformed random variable
$$W_i := \frac{\lambda_i\exp(-e_i(g(Z),a))}{\sum_{j=1}^N\lambda_j\exp(-e_j(g(Z), a))}.
$$

**Question:**

- *(A)* What is a "good estimator" for expected value of $W$ ?
- *(B)* For which choices of the parameters $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_N$ is the variance of $W_i$ minimized ?

**Setting:**
I want to estimate the expectations of the $W_i$'s to good precision. Indeed, if possible I'd prefer to minimize all the $\operatorname{Var}(W_i)$ at once, i.e solve
$$\underset{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_N>0}{\operatorname{minimize}}\;\max_{i} \operatorname{Var}(W_i).
$$
I considered the decoupled problems for convenience (presumably much easier).

Comment: Notation is better now. What is the application of this problem?

Comment: Semi-discrete optimal transport. Transporting the pushforward of  a Guassian under $g$, unto a sum of Dirac masses. Solution of the above problems is essential for doing gradient updates which don't blow-up.

Comment: Do you have example instances of g? What are the simplest instances of g of practical; interest?

Comment: No, $g$ is essentially a black-box (e.g neural network).

Comment: @MarkL.Stone if you want, you may consider that $g$ is an affine function; this is always valid locally (by differentiability).

Comment: What is your actual objective? If you look at any one individual $W_i$, you can "minimize" its variance by setting $\lambda_i = "\epsilon$", and all other $\lambda_j = 1$.  Do you have an aggregate objective across all $W_I$?  Maybe you want to minimize the maximum $Var(W_i)$ across all i 's? And do you really need to minimize (some function of) them, or just have them bounded below some value (to prevent some blow up? What really is needed to prevent gradient blow up?  Do you really want to control maximum of $W_i$, not variance or expected value per se?

Comment: All I have are samples $z_1,\ldots,z_M \sim \mathcal N_k$ from which I want to estimate the expectations of the $W_i$'s to good precision. Indeed, if possible I'd prefer to minimize all the $\operatorname{Var}(W_i)$ at once, i.e solve $\operatorname{minimize}_{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_N}\max_{i} \operatorname{Var}(W_i)$.  I considered the decoupled problems for convenience (presumably much easier). Your suggestion is is interesting. Do you mean set $\lambda_i$ to something very small while fixing all the others to $1$ ?

Comment: That suggestion was really meant to flesh out your formulation, which the minimax does.Why do you care about EW? What is it you really need to prevent or reduce probability of gradient blow up? Why are you limited to m samples of  Normal vector? Do you know the mean and covariance of that Normal, in which case can you generate and use additional samples if you want? Are those m samples the same ones you are using in the calculation of whatever gradient you are trying to prevent from blowing up? It seems you haven't really yet conveyed the full problem, so we won't really solve correct problem.

Comment: $\mathbb E[W]$ is the gradient of an objective function. Yes the mean and covariance of the normal are completely known. You can consider $M$ as large as you will, but this will come at a price, as it will affect the overall running time of the overall optimization procedure (evaluating $g$ is costly, etc.).

Comment: EW is gradient, but when you change $\lambda_i$ 's you change EW?  Do you then make a correction of some kind to make it all work out? Does this amount to importance sampling? I have no idea what the $y_i$ 's are, so still really don't have a clue what's going on. If you devote yourself to writing out everything more completely, even if it doesn't help you get an answer/suggestion from a reader, it may serve to clarify your own thinking. The whole problem seems perhaps too complicated for a nice forum answer that's really on the money, as opposed to solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Thanks for the persistent interest. Believe me, those details (what's $y_i$'s, etc.) won't clarify the problem :). They will only add problem-specific noise and distract the reader from the essence of the problem. That notwithstanding, let me just say that the $\lambda_i$'s can be thought of as the degeneracies of a thermodynamic system with temperature-normalized (random) energy levels ei. The $y_i$'s are the states, the temperature is very low (the low temp. limit  of the $W_i$'s is independent of the degeneracies...). Also, yes you can indeed see this as importance sampling (hence the tag).

Comment: Simpler  problem: Get rid of denominator in $W_i$, Denote $Q_i$ as random variable $\exp(-e_i(g(Z),a))$. Use your sample to estimate $Var(Q_i) \forall i$. 1st assume $Q_i$ uncorrelated. Impose constraints $\lambda_i \ge 0 \forall i, \Sigma\lambda_i = 1$. Then $Var(\Sigma \lambda_iQ_i)$ is minimized by $\lambda_i = 1/Var(Q_i)/\Sigma(1/Var(Q_i))$. For correlated $Q_i$ w/ estimated cov. matrix $C$, optimal $\lambda_i$ = ith column of $C^{-1}$ divided by sum of all elements of $C^{-1}$. Maybe you can solve more complicated version (if you need it) using KKT conditions, else numerical optimization.

Comment: Typo in my previous comment: Should be: optimal $\lambda_i$ =  SUM OF ith column of $C^{-1}$ divided by sum of all elements of $C^{-1}$

Comment: I just came across https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301108/minimize-the-variance-of-a-boltzmann-distribution and your comment "I mean to replace the integrands exp(...)/∑jexp(...) with another random quantity of same expectation (or approx the same), but with smaller variance. " That sounds like control variates (variables), which can be an effective variance reduction technique. If that's what you're trying to do, you should say so. But in control variates, you generally need or want the control variable's expected value to be known very accurately - I don't see my above solution qualifying